# No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public whilst using a CLI-deployed function

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, serilog, servicebus

I appreciate there are a few of these questions, but I'm fairly certain I've been through everything and have reached the 'what the hell' point.

I'm pushing out a v3 Function to Azure and having no luck in actually getting the Function to.....function. I'm worried that the Azure CLI task is breaking something.

The startup of my function is:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(TestFunction.Startup))]

namespace TestFunction
{

    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            // Config
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

            // Level
            LogEventLevel logLevel;
            switch (config["SerilogLoggingLevel"])
            {
                case "Error":
                    logLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                    break;
                case "Warning":
                    logLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
                    break;
                case "Information":
                    logLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
                    break;
                case "Debug":
                    logLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                    break;
                default:
                    logLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
                    break;
            }

            // Load the logger from the settings
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(workspaceId: config["SerilogWorkspaceId"],
                                        authenticationId: config["SerilogAuthId"],
                                        logName: config["SerilogName"],
                                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: logLevel)
                .CreateLogger();

            // Add the logger
            builder.Services.AddLogging(c => c.AddSerilog(logger));

            // Starting
            Log.Information("Starting up!");

        }

    }

}
```

And the function inside:

```
public class TestEventTrigger
{

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public TestEventTrigger(
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    [FunctionName("TestEvent")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testevent", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]Message incomingMessage)
    {

        Log.Debug("Message received: '" + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(incomingMessage.Body) + "'");


    }

}
```

I'm fairly certain I have all the packages installed. Browsing to the Function seems to be OK via the web.

Nothing shows in the custom log in Log Analytics, either. The table does get created though.

The release is done using:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip
```

Comment: Update: Looks like the following doesn't update the app: 

az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g rg-secret-rg -n jci-secret-app-name --src $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/secret-project/secret/packages/Function.zip

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it wasn't pushing to the app correctly, but failing silently. Fixed the deployment, and all is good.